# Any way to fix this error, in line: "std=float(line)-average ValueError: could not convert string to float"

Tags: python, python-3.x

for the line     std=float(line)-average ValueError: could not convert string to float, I get the error listed above. I am trying to calculate the standard deviation for the integers in the referenced list(RandomNumber.txt)

```
def main():
    numbersFile=open("RandomNumber.txt" , 'r')

    line=numbersFile.readline()
    total=0
    numberoflines=0

    while line != "":

        numberoflines+=1
        total+=float(line)
        line=numbersFile.readline().strip()
        average=total/numberoflines

        std=float(line)-average

        deviation=float((std**2))/float(numberoflines)


    print("The average is: " , average) 
    print("The standard deviation of the numbers is: ", deviation)


main()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: This program requires a data file we don't have.  You should be able to hard-code the problem lines into a list and iterate through that.  If nothing else, provide a couple of file lines that will provoke the problem.

Comment: The basic problem is likely that you have something in the line that is not part of a legal float.  For instance, did you forget to strip off the line feed?

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
def main():
    numbersFile=open("RandomNumber.txt" , 'r')

line=numbersFile.readline()
total=0
numberoflines=0

while line != "":

    numberoflines+=1
    total+=float(line)


    line=numbersFile.readline().rstrip('\n') #had to read the line inside the loop and after  converted to float
numbersFile.seek(0) #used .seek(0) to go back and read file from beginning 
average=total/numberoflines #removed from loop to calculate final iteraton, instead of creating a new avg every loop
line=numbersFile.readline()
total=0
while line !="":  #added this while loop to seperatly calculate the standard deviatoin from the average
    line=float(line)-average
    a=line**2
    total+=a
    line=numbersFile.readline() 
std=math.sqrt(total/numberoflines)







print("The average is: " , average)

print("The standard deviation of the numbers is: " , std)


main()
```